# Gnuplot downsample and average 3d plot in gnuplot with NaN

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, nan

I am using 
splot "testdata.txt" nonuniform matrix

data.txt is sparse in some places and dense in others.  I would like to average the dense values to reduce the noise in the plot.  The obvious way to do this is

set dgrid3d

However, it appears that when the file contains "NaN", nothing is plotted.

```
set zrange [0:4]
splot "testdata.txt" nonuniform matrix
set dgrid3d
splot "testdata.txt" nonuniform matrix
```

example data:

```
4 1 2 3
1 0 1 2
2 1 2 3
3 2 3 NaN
```

How can I achieve downsampling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with filtering out the "NaN" values as suggested by Bernhard is that it also removes all the data in the same row of the "NaN" value. If you can do without that data, then that is a way to proceed. If you want to keep that data, then I would suggest that you change "NaN" by a very specific number you don't expect will come up and use that to tell gnuplot to ignore those using a conditional plot with the `1/0` option:

```
splot "< sed 's/NaN/12345/g' testdata.txt" nonuniform matrix \
u 1:2:($3 == 12345 ? 1/0 : $3)
```

[image]

Comment: Could you not do `$3==NaN`?

Comment: I thought, that the `1/0` would mess the grid structure and wouldn't allow to use `with lines`. But your solution works fine :)

Comment: Thank you.  Hopefully 1/0 is implemented sanely.

Comment: why does
`splot '< sed "s/NaN/1\/0/g" testdata.txt' nonuniform matrix`
produce the value 3, 3, 3?

Comment: I think the z value produced is less than 3. Anyway it's a product of the interpolation used. You can use different interpolation schemes with dgrid3d. Try the help for a list.

Answer (score 0):

Using at least gnuplot 4.6.3 the `NaN` is automatically set to zero. Using the script

```
set dgrid3d
set ticslevel 0
splot 'testdata.txt' nonuniform matrix w l notitle
```

gives (with 4.6.3):

[image]

If this guess to set NaN values to zero is wrong for you, you should use a non gridded data format with

```
<x0> <y0> <z0>
<x1> <y1> <z1>
etc.
```

since you're using `dgrid3d` anyway to create gridded data. Then you can also use Bernhard's solution to filter out the NaN values.

Comment: Is assuming NaN=0 a bug in gnuplot?  Considering it seems to override "set datafile missing"?

Comment: Turning a giant nonuniform matrix into the nongridded data format seems a bit impractical.

Comment: Maybe, but having a sparse matrix stored in matrix format also isn't the best choice. I've always stored my huge experimental data sets as [tag:hdf5] data files which you can then convert on-the-fly (maybe with filtering) with `splot '< h5totxt -s " " file.h5' ...`.